# FFMPEG providing support for HEVC decoding

Tags: video, ffmpeg, decoder, hevc, h.265

FFMPEG v2.1 onwards is providing support for HEVC Decoding. I tried an elementary input bin stream as an input for it and yes i got a corresponding YUV file.

Now my question is, since i'm just passing an elementary stream as an input, how is the decoder parsing it?

I have gone through the `/libavformat/hevcdec.c` which is supposed to be a demuxer for `HEVC`.
I know `hevc_probe()` is the function in `hevcdec.c` where it detects if the file can be decoded by the HEVC decoder.

The definition of hevc_probe() function is given below:

```
static int hevc_probe(AVProbeData *p)
{
    uint32_t code = -1;
    int vps = 0, sps = 0, pps = 0, irap = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < p->buf_size - 1; i++) {
        code = (code << 8) + p->buf[i];
        if ((code & 0xffffff00) == 0x100) {
            uint8_t nal2 = p->buf[i + 1];
            int type = (code & 0x7E) >> 1;

            if (code & 0x81) // forbidden and reserved zero bits
                return 0;

            if (nal2 & 0xf8) // reserved zero
                return 0;

            switch (type) {
            case NAL_VPS:        vps++;  break;
            case NAL_SPS:        sps++;  break;
            case NAL_PPS:        pps++;  break;
            case NAL_BLA_N_LP:
            case NAL_BLA_W_LP:
            case NAL_BLA_W_RADL:
            case NAL_CRA_NUT:
            case NAL_IDR_N_LP:
            case NAL_IDR_W_RADL: irap++; break;
            }
        }
    }

    // printf("vps=%d, sps=%d, pps=%d, irap=%d\n", vps, sps, pps, irap);

    if (vps && sps && pps && irap)
        return AVPROBE_SCORE_EXTENSION + 1; // 1 more than .mpg
    return 0;
}
```

According to whatever i have read, only if this function returns a constant of type `AVPROBE_SCORE_EXTENSION`, the decoding will proceed. However it is returning `AVPROBE_SCORE_EXTENSION+1` Why is it?

Also as seen above in the code, they are deciding some `type` variable from the input bit code obtained and performing increment in the constants like sps, pps, etc. Is the the normal operation that needs to be performed by a parser which can decode an elementary stream?

It would be really helpful to everyone if anyone is able to give a brief of a parser of a decoder that can decode an elementary stream.

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Automatically detecting the type of a data stream is a probabilistic matter. A certain probe function looks for files of a certain data type, but can it be absolutely certain that the data conforms to that type? What about false positives? For example, a lot of multimedia files have signatures in the first 4 bytes that consist of 4 ASCII characters. If a probe function checked for those 4 characters and it found a random text file happened to begin with the same 4 characters, that would be a false positive.

Since there are various factors that can influence detection, FFmpeg's probe functions return a certainty value ranging from 0..100 ("definitely does NOT conform" .. "absolute is this type"). `AVPROBE_SCORE_EXTENSION` is defined as 50. Some file types don't have strong signatures and the best that a probe function can do is check the file's extension.

Where I'm going with all of this: Elementary streams can be a bit tricky to automatically detect. That's why, after gathering enough evidence, the HEVC elementary stream probe detection only has enough confidence to return 51% probability that this stream is HEVC. As FFmpeg runs the stream through various probe functions, another format's probe function could override this one if it returns higher than 51% certainty.

It should be noted that elementary streams are not commonly seen "in the wild". They tend to be packaged into other formats that are better for transport and processing (see program streams and transport streams).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One last thing that will really help me is: In which section of the code do i need to specify the extension of my input file? Currently the HEVC code uses .bin as an input file, so in which section should i specify this. Please do reply for this. Also what is MKTAG? is it something related to input file extensions?

Comment: I'm still a bit unclear on what you're trying to accomplish. Taken with another of your questions that I just answered, I could construe that you're trying to create your own demuxer/decoder pair. Is that right? About MKTAG: That just takes 4 ASCII characters and turns them into a 32-bit number, aka, a FourCC (prevalent in multimedia file formats) but not pertinent to file extensions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes i'm creating a demuxer and decoder pair. My goal is whenever a .bin file is given as an input my decoder should be invoked. So i need to know where i need to specify for the extension check. Agreed that i should not depend on the file extension as any fake file with a .bin can be given as an input. However for now i need to do this demuxer with the assumption that i'm always providing a proper.bin file as an input. Please help.

Comment: As long as you're developing this privately and there is no definite signature in the file format, you could always hardwire the probe function to return 100 (i.e., 100% certainty that this demuxer handles the format). If you're developing a new file format to place into "the wild", please consider a more definite signature.

Comment: If 100 is returned it means AVPROBE_SCORE_MAX. So what does this stands for? Or if i want to make a new file format say .hevc, then what shall i do? Is there any place where strcmp for the extensions are being performed?

Comment: One more thing i forgot to specify, since i'm using an elementary bin stream, there is no audio in it. Hence the only purpose for me making this demuxer is that, it should recognize the extension i want and invoke my decoder to decode it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42172/discussion-between-sam-and-multimedia-mike)

Comment: No i'm not writing a new HEVC decoder,  i have taken the HM reference code for HEVC and modified some stuff to meet my requirements.